convert timestamp with offset to utc timestamp in python?
I have a dataframe with a column in it -
date_col
2024-05-12T17:46:50.746922-07:00
2024-05-12T17:31:35.438304-07:00
2024-05-12T17:46:50.642095-07:00
2024-05-12T17:02:02.299320-07:00

I tried below code -
df['updated'] = datetime.fromisoformat(str(df['date_col'])).astimezone(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")

But its giving error -
TypeError: fromisoformat: argument must be str
print(type(df['date_col'])) gives <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(df.dypes) gives date_col object

Expected output is in form of - 2024-05-13T00:46:50.746Z
Any help is appreciated.

It would appear that the str function is not creating a string from the field in your table. What is the actual data in the table and where does it come from?

I have edited the types part, if you can answer me based on  that.

It is not working because you are trying to convert entire date_col series to a string and then process it as a single datetime object. datetime.fromisoformat expects you to give a single string, not a series of strings.

That's what I am asking , how can we convert that utc offset timestamp to proper datetime format ?

You need to extract each item one by one from the rows in your table and convert them individually. So you need a loop that iterates through the rows of your table.

I'd try something like this:
import pandas as pd
import pytz

# Convert the column to datetime objects
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], utc=True)

# Convert to UTC and format as expected
df['updated'] = df['date_col'].dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

Some explanation:

pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], utc=True): This line converts the date_col column to datetime objects, assuming that the strings in the column represent UTC times.
df['date_col'].dt.tz_convert('UTC'): This converts the datetime objects to UTC timezone. The dt accessor is used for datetime operations in pandas.
df['date_col'].dt.tz_convert('UTC').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'): This line converts the UTC datetime objects to the desired string format using the strftime method. The format string '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ' represents the expected output format, where %f is used for microseconds and Z represents the UTC timezone.

After running this code, the updated column in your DataFrame should contain the expected output format.
!!! If the strings in your date_col are not already in UTC, you'll need to adjust the pd.to_datetime call to specify the correct timezone or format.

from datetime import datetime, import pytz why these imports?

You are right, from datetime import datetime is redundant here, I had another solution in my head originally. But you need import pytz if you want to run dt.tz_convert function.

nope, you don't need pytz either (pytz is deprecated since Python 3.9 by the way). pandas has time zone handling built-in (was based on pytz in the past, is based on zoneinfo nowadays).

I think you can do it like this,
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame date time data stored as string.
data = {
    'date_col': [
        '2024-05-12T17:46:50.746922-07:00',
        '2024-05-12T17:31:35.438304-07:00',
        '2024-05-12T17:46:50.642095-07:00',
        '2024-05-12T17:02:02.299320-07:00'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Converting the date_col to timezone-aware datetime objects using pd.to_datetime.
# Convert date_col to datetime objects with timezone information
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])

# Convert to UTC and format
df['updated'] = (df['date_col'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')
                 .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3] + 'Z')

# Check if this is what you wanted
print(df)

